# how to split an object up in camel routebuilder

Tags: java, apache-camel

Hi there I'm pretty new to Java, camel, etc.  Here's my problem:

I have code that passes an order containing order items and some other info in xml format from one camel Processor to another.  This particular Processor then splits up the order and creates multiple orders, and then passes them all on to the next endpoint as separate messages.

Currently this Processor uses ProducerTemplate to explicitly accomplish this.  I would like to  move this behaviour to RouteBuilder itself and not use ProducerTemplate.  I've looked at Splitter and MessageTranslator, but I don't have all the pieces yet I think.

So basically I want to split the message in the RouteBuilder using Splitter, but I want to supply custom code that will take the message, then deserialize it into an Order object, then create multiple Order objects, and then send them all as separate messages to the next endpoint.  How do I accomplish this?

e.g. I want to be able to do something like

```
from("startPoint").split(MyCustomStrategy).to("endPoint")

//where MyCustomStrategy will take the message, 
//and split it up and pass all the newly created messages to endPoint.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a bean or processor in your route which creates the `Order` objects and returns them as a collection (e.g., `List<Order>` or similar). Splitter EIP can then be used to process each `Order` in that collection, one at a time by e.g. passing each order to another processor/bean that handles a single order, possibly continuing on to another endpoint as needed, etc.

```
// Pseudocode:
from(input).
to(bean-which-returns-a-collection-of-orders).
split(on-the-body).
to(bean-which-processes-a-single-order).
to(anywhere-else-needed-for-your-purposes).
// etc...
```

Or something along those lines; sorry, I use Spring DSL not Java DSL but camel docs show both. Here's some actual spring DSL code where a collection is being split to process each item in the collection:

```
        <split>
              <simple>${body}</simple>
              <doTry>
                 <log message="A.a1 -- splitting batches for transfer" loggingLevel="DEBUG" />
                 <setHeader headerName="currentBatchNumber">
                    <simple>${body.batchNumber}</simple>
                 </setHeader>
                 <setHeader headerName="CamelFileName">
                    <simple>${body.batchNumber}.xml</simple>
                 </setHeader>
                 <log message="A.a2 -- marshalling a single batch to XML" loggingLevel="DEBUG" />
                 <marshal>
                     <jaxb prettyPrint="true" contextPath="generated.gov.nmcourts.ecitation"
                       partClass="generated.gov.nmcourts.ecitation.NMCitationEFileBatch"
                       partNamespace="EFileBatch" />
                 </marshal>

                 <log message="A.a3 -- xslt transform to add schema location" loggingLevel="DEBUG" />
                 <to uri="{{addSchemaLocationXsltUri}}"/>

                 <log message="A.a4 -- ftp now initiating" loggingLevel="DEBUG" />
                 <log message="ftping $simple{in.header.CamelFileName}" loggingLevel="DEBUG"/>

                 <bean ref="markFtpStatusOnTickets"/>
                 <to uri="{{ftpOdysseyInputPath}}"/>
                 <log message="A.a5 -- ftp now complete" loggingLevel="DEBUG" />
                 <doCatch>
                    <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                    <handled>
                       <constant>true</constant>
                    </handled>
                    <bean ref="ticketExceptionHandler" method="handleException"/>
                 </doCatch>
              </doTry>
          </split>
```